# I can't register event CollectionChanged of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection

I try to run some code when collection is changed. I keep collection as property in Data class:

```
public static ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> DeviceAdjustedConfigurations
{
     get { return deviceAdjustedConfigurations; }
     set { deviceAdjustedConfigurations = value; }
}
```

and register it in code like that:

```
Data.DeviceAdjustedConfigurations.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DeviceAdjustedConfigurationsCollectionChanged);
```

But after registration `CollectionChanged` is `null` and the appropriate code in delegated method is not run. In this place `DeviceAdjustedConiguration` already contains some data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use the set method? If you set a new collection changes to the old one won't trigger collectionchanged in the new.. Or do you check immediately after you add the event handler?

Comment: Yes, I use set. Does it mean that I overrid the collection which I registered once with the new instance which is not registered by me? 

    Data.DeviceAdjustedConfigurations = adjustedConfiguration;

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I stoped one line before seting new value and the  delegate was set and after set new collection to my property it set to null. Is there some nice way to handle collection as property with easy handle of genereated events? Should I change seter somehow?

Comment: Why are you setting the collection? Can't you just add new items to the existing one? You rarely have to recreate a collection.

Comment: I have some list of supported configurations and dependly which device I handle I create list for current device which base on list of all configurations. So sometimes the list is almost empty, and sometimes it is almost full and I want to refresh combobox according to changes in supproted device list (no, I don't know how to do it with binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid having a set property accessor for collection types, one reason being the one you experienced here with events. Another problem is if someone caches the collection and adds items to it later.

```
var old = obj.DeviceAdjustedConfigurations;
obj.DeviceAdjustedConfigurations = new ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration>();
old.Add(new OfferedConfiguration()); // what should happen here?
```

instead, remove the set-accessor and use the existing collection directly.

```
obj.DeviceAdjustedConfigurations.Add(new OfferedConfiguration());
```

---

If you really need to set the collection, you need to handle this with for instance a property change event from the class that owns the `DeviceAdjustedConfigurations`.

```
public class Item
{
    public static ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> DeviceAdjustedConfigurations
    {
        get { return deviceAdjustedConfigurations; }
        set
        {
            if (deviceAdjustedConfigurations != value)
            {
                onDeviceConfigurationsChanging(deviceAdjustedConfigurations, value);
                deviceAdjustedConfigurations = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<ConfigurationChangedEventArgs> DeviceConfigurationsChanging;

    private static void onDeviceConfigurationsChanging(
        ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> oldList,
        ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> newList)
    {
        var handler = DeviceConfigurationsChanging;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, new ConfigurationChangedEventArgs(oldList, newList));
        }
    }
}

public class ConfigurationChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ConfigurationChangedEventArgs(
        ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> oldList,
        ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> newList)
    {
        OldList = oldList;
        NewList = newList;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> OldList { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<OfferedConfiguration> NewList { get; private set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Item.DeviceConfigurationsChanging += updateEvents;
    }

    private void updateEvents(object sender, ConfigurationChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.OldList.CollectionChanged -= onCollectionChanged;
        args.NewList.CollectionChanged += onCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void onCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) { }
}
```

Comment: After your answer I was thinking about switching the registered degeleate from old collection to the new one. Now I see how it should be done. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, there's alot of hassle when allowing setting of collections, so it's easier to just use the collections as they are.